# How do i make Border 100% Width?

Tags: border

css - https://codepaste.net/3we9vf

im making a webpage from "scratch" but im having trouble with the these borders im trying to put. The bottom border of the navbar doesnt go all the 100%width and the aside right border doesnt go all the way up. Help ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0X28.png)

Comment: show us your css. Its probably a margin or padding issue.

Comment: @rjustin what is the proper way to share it ?

Comment: Edit your question and you will see 2 curly brackets. click that and paste it there. Code just needs to be indented 4 spaces.

Comment: @rjustin wasnt able to share it ... put it in a link. sorry for the inconvenience it may bring

Comment: @rjustin this is the html https://codepaste.net/mrffob

Comment: Something is missing. Get this codepen looking like the image and I can help you from there. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMjRQw

Comment: Are there any other libraries being used?

Comment: @rjustin https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGMOKE here you are

Comment: Take a look at my answer. If it is to your satisfaction please accept to help future users.

Comment: @rjustin Thanks ! Didnt even know that was there cause the code aint mine and i dont even know what that > * is meant for

Comment: @rjustin ill try but it seems like everyone here knows alot more then me xD

Comment: Accepting just lets other find the answer quicker, you wont have to do any extra work. Dont worrry keep practicing and you will become very knowledgable.  By the way '*' or star refers to all or any and is often called a wildcard.

Comment: @rjustin are you there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue was with padding in the .wrapper class CSS. Heres a working version: [Working](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzaLRO)  All I did was removed the 10px padding. If you want certain things padded it should be done on a more case by case basis.

```
    .wrapper > * {
    //no paddding
    flex: 1 100%;
}
```